# On master node : Failed construction of Regionserver : java.net.BindException

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have a 4-node cluster(hadoop 2.5.2) (Hbase 1.0.0) with a master(as salve) and 3 slaves on the master machine. After calling start-hbase.sh, the jps does not show the HRegionServer process running on the master but is ruuning fine on all the three slaves.

the log file on the master shows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Regionserver: class     org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.constructRegionServer(HRegionServer.java:2487)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.start(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.run(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:87)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.main(HRegionServer.java:2502)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.constructRegionServer(HRegionServer.java:2485)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to hadoopmaster.mst.edu/172.16.195.58:16020 : Address already in use
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.bind(RpcServer.java:2371)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer$Listener.<init>(RpcServer.java:524)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.<init>(RpcServer.java:1899)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:790)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.createRpcServices(HRegionServer.java:575)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:492)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.bind(RpcServer.java:2369)
... 15 more
```

Comment: Same issue, the port is used by HMaster.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a number of issues in HBase 1.0.x: [HBASE-11575](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11575), [HBASE-13453](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-13453) and [HBASE-13479](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-13479).

A workaround mentioned in [this comment on HBASE-13479](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-13479?focusedCommentId=14555938&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14555938) is to manually configure the following ports in `hbase-site.xml`:

- `hbase.regionserver.port`
- `hbase.master.info.port`
- `hbase.regionserver.info.port`

Upgrading to HBase 1.1.x is another option (worked for me).